# PHP reference no effect

Tags: php, reference

I want to have a reference to an object in an array so I can change it later. In this case I am increasing the score of a particular user:

```
$guessing_user;
foreach($this->UUID_users[$UUID] as &$othr_user){
    if($othr_user['user_object'] == $user){
        $guessing_user=$othr_user;
        break;
    }
}
$guessing_user['score']+=10;
```

When I look in array at the original value ('score') it stays the same. I am probably missing something about references. Isn't the `&` sign in `foreach` enough?

Comment: You are passing $$othr_user by reference. If you change $othr_user in the foreach, $this->UUID_users[SOMEKEY] will be changed after the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$guessing_user = &$othr_user;
```

I think PHP makes a copy when you set `$guessing_user`.